# How to assert the value of an optional Bool in Swift unit test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, option-type

I have a Swift unit test similar to the following:

```
var firstArgumentInClosure: Bool?
someFunc { firstArgumentInClosure = $0 }
XCTAssertTrue(firstArgumentInClosure?)
```

I'm trying to assert the closure was called with the first argument being `true`.

This doesn't compile with error message:

> '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

One way I can fix this is by changing the assertion to:

```
XCTAssertEqualTrue(firstArgumentInClosure ?? false)
```

Is there no more concise way to do this? It's a bit strange to see the `??
 false`. I also don't want to implicitly unwrap the optional with `!` because I don't want that to crash the test, I just want the test to fail if `firstArgumentInClosure` is `nil` or `false`. I also want to avoid any `if let`s to keep things concise.

Similarly, how would I write such an assertion when I'm trying to use `XCTAssertFalse` to ensure a `Bool?` is `false`?

Comment: What's wrong with `XCTAssertEqualTrue(firstArgumentInClosure ?? false)`?

Comment: If the test fails it's not clear if the closure was never called or the closure was called with the wrong argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cleanest approach I found is:

```
XCTAssertEqual(firstArgumentInClosure, true)
```

Or if I want to assert it's false:

```
XCTAssertEqual(firstArgumentInClosure, false)
```

This doesn't require unwrapping the optional.

Answer (score 5):

Optional types require more effort to test because of an extra state.

You can use `XCTAssertTrue(firstArgumentInClosure ?? false)` to test for `true` and `XCTAssertFalse(firstArgumentInClosure ?? true)` to test for `false`. However, this is not ideal, because it mixes up failures due to `nil` with failures due to receiving an opposite value.

A better (but much longer) approach uses `if let` to unwrap the result for testing:

```
if let unwrappedFirstArg = firstArgumentInClosure {
    XCTAssertFalse(unwrappedFirstArg)
} else {
    XCTFail("Received nil in firstArgumentInClosure")
}
```

Now your test output would identify the problem precisely, making it easier for you to investigate the issue.